# give runtime href of a link that doesn't set in source code

Tags: php, jquery, html, runtime, aes

How to give href of a link that set in runtime not in html source code:

there is a download link in a webpage:

`<a id="downloadLink" href="">...</a>`

but in runtime that link has a href:

`<a id="downloadLink" href="http://www.example.com/download/s/eyJjdCI6IkFpc003OERmME1uS3dhR1BQcXg1ckE9PSIsIml2IjoiNzg0OGI5NWRmMmRjZDg0ZjFlMjVjYTM3MjY1MjdjMTUiLCJzIjoiYjU1NTIyN2Q2MmJiODAyMSJ9.mp3">...</a>`

I searched in html source and find that it use jquery aes to encrypt and set the link.

How can I access to runtime source code by PHP? `file_get_contents()` give me source html code not runtime code

Comment: Please improve your question .

Answer (score 1):

with use of PHP

```
<a id="downloadLink" href="<?php echo $url?>" download></a>
```

with use of Jquery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#downloadLink").attr('href','example@example.com');
      $("#downloadLink").attr('download','download');
    });
  </script>
```

I hope the above code helps

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it like the code below. Initialize the variable (`$url`) to a url value, then use it to set `href=""` value.

```
<?php

$url =  "http://www.example.com/download/s/eyJjdCI6IkFpc003OERmME1uS3dhR1BQcXg1ckE9PSIsIml2IjoiNzg0OGI5NWRmMmRjZDg0ZjFlMjVjYTM3MjY1MjdjMTUiLCJzIjoiYjU1NTIyN2Q2MmJiODAyMSJ9.mp3";

?>

<a id="downloadLink" href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Text To Show</a>
```